# Who wrote "How Much for Just the Planet"?

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

Does anyone know about a short story named "How Much for Just the Planet?"

Comment: @Richard is 250+ pages a "short story"?

Comment: @phantom42 Compared to *The Lord of the Rings* or *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, yes.

Comment: @sbj3: it looks like you're new here, so I thought I'd explain - when something is relatively easy to find on your own, asking it here tends to get negative votes on the question (for lack of research).

Answer (score 1):

There's a 1987 [novel of that name](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/How_Much_for_Just_the_Planet%3F) by John M. Ford.

[image: The book cover showing a man in coattails standing on a green landscape with Worf's and Kirk's heads superimposed onto the blue sky]

Comment: I've never read that one, but since it has Mister Mxyzptlk on the cover, I may have to now.